# Segue won't work to display text on a lavel

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Okay, so I have two storyboards being incorporated into my code. One of them being the coffeeViewController, the other being the checkoutViewController. I have an array of doubles and different values incorporated into it. However, when I run the code, it shows the label that I want to edit as blank. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

**This code is on my coffeeViewController**

```
var total:[Double] = []

@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        let sum = total.reduce(0,+)
        let number = "\(sum)"
        let lvc = segue.destination as! checkoutViewController
        lvc.am = number
    }
}
```

**This code is on my checkoutViewController**

```
var am = String()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    amount.text = am
}
```

Comment: This isn't SwiftUI

Comment: Are you sure your `amount` is hooked up in the Storyboard? If you change `= String()` to `= "Test"` does it show `Test`?

Comment: Is `prepare(for:sender:)` even called? Because currently, it's inside `action(_:)` method... And that's strange...